# Closing questions should be easier in the Triage queue

Tags: discussion, triage

After using the Triage queue for a few days, I've marked many questions unsalvageable.  However, I've *always* used a close reason; I have not run into *anything* that should be flagged.

Right now, voting to close requires five steps:

1. Click Unsalvageable
2. Find "Should be closed for another reason" in the middle of the list of flags
3. Click "Should be closed for another reason"
4. Select a close reason
5. Click Close

It's not *that* difficult, but the mental overhead of finding the close option in the list is annoying, especially when I'm used to going straight to the close vote menu either from the "close" option on a question or from the Close Votes queue.

If a reviewer has the cast close votes privilege, they should see two buttons <kbd>Unsalvageable (Close)</kbd> and <kbd>Unsalvageable (Flag)</kbd> to mirror the normal way they interact with those functions.

Comment: I'd *really* like the ability to take action based on the "should be improved" too.  Bring me to a page where I can optimally flag/close or edit the question (and then move on to the next question in the triage queue).

Comment: Tidying up the UI would be a good idea. Another problem, beside what's in your post is two ways of reaching the "duplicate" reason. That's a symptom of chaos.

Comment: I hear ya - using the flagging dialog to select a close reason *really* sucks. Triaging has been a real eye-opener for me; **this is the UI we expect the majority of users to interact with when they see a problem!**

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278734/triage-queues-unsalvageable-should-not-prompt-for-a-reason/

Answer (score 31):

I think we all agree on the problem with the current system.

The definition of unsalvageable in my opinion is that of the current VLQ or SPAM flag. That's why I was withholding even to try to hit <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> button. Then I found out it is for stuff that can be salvaged too, but now needs to be closed.

To make life easier I would suggest to remove the <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> button and replace it with a <kbd>Flag</kbd> and <kbd>Close</kbd> button.

If you want to, you could even keep the <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> button for flagging, but I would prefer to get rid of it.

Comment: I suppose the point of the queue is Triage rather than treatment. Perhaps that's why the Edit option is not available.

Comment: I know, add another button named `I'll deal with it`.

Comment: Well, actually, 'close' doesn't especially mean 'unsalvageable' because the question is 'on hold' and can be improved. 'Unsalvageable' should be for VLQ, spam and offensive only.

Comment: @DanubianSailor: That was my idea too, and the post suggests that.

Comment: Maybe the close option should be associated with `Needs Improvement` instead of `Unsalvageable`?  I'm not sure if that makes sense, but it does seem to fit the triage idea a little better than adding an extra button.

Comment: @Kevin: That is a good option too.

Comment: It's also weird when you see an Unsalvagable question, but are out of close votes for the day.  Do you just click "Needs Improvement", or move on and hope someone else flags it as Unsalvageable?

Comment: @Lit good point. Doesn't make sense either. I think we need more close votes.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your proposal, but I think the button row would become very wide if you have both <kbd>Unsalvageable (Close)</kbd> and <kbd>Unsalvageable (Flag)</kbd> buttons, and this might look ugly on smaller screens because the buttons would either overlap the explanation text or there would be two separate rows.

Therefore, I suggest something different: have two tabs in the dialog that pops up, a "Close" tab (selected by default) and a "Flag" tab, which contains the other flag options. Then it's fine to have just one <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> button.

Comment: While I agree that the button names are too long right now, I disagree that creating a new UI element is the right solution.  That's basically the same problem I have right now.

Comment: @davidism: You're proposing adding a new UI element (the extra button).