# Triage Queue's "Unsalvageable" should not prompt for a reason

Tags: discussion, triage

According to the post that introduced the Triage queue, [the purpose of it is to be fast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage#comment124948_278444). Indeed, as fast as can be, because "because we're throwing a ridiculous number of questions into it."

Clicking "Looks OK" and "Needs Improvement" immediately takes you to the next question. They're fast.

Clicking "Unsalvageable" does not: it instead prompts you for what amounts to a close reason. It's very slow.

Reviewers shouldn't need to justify the reason they think a question is unsalvageable. Please put these posts straight in the low quality queue, or the close queue, or wherever they belong. It's "needs triage"; it's not "needs immediate and final action".

Comment: Putting in the close queue with what no reason?  You need to give some reason why you think it is unsalvageable - close reason, etc.

Comment: @bluefeet: Why not? If the queue is supposed to be fast, I fail to see why one should justify anything. Or then, add some kind of "Fix this now" button, for good samaritains who want to immediately do whatever edits are needed to improve the offending questions.

Comment: Why do you assume that the queue is supposed to be fast?  You should be reviewing the posts to see what should happen to it, I don't see how that is supposed to be fast...unless you are robo-reviewing.  I don't think you should be making any of these decisions fast.

Comment: @bluefeet: because that's how it was presented in the "help us test question triage!" post? e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage#comment124364_278380 or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage#comment124948_278444

Comment: I disagree that processing these should be fast.  Yes, you can make an immediate decision that a post is good or bad but you need to provide a reason - vote to close, flag, etc. why a post should be removed and that takes time.

Comment: If it's garbage, you should be able to describe why it's garbage.

Comment: @bluefeet: except that it's redundant. If the flow is "triage" -> "wherever it belongs", then there's an extra step in "wherever it belongs" where an extra number of reviewers end up needing to agree or disagree on whether it should be closed or whatever.

Comment: @bluefeet fast is of course relative, but a core design of Triage has been stated that it should indeed be fast.  It's an expressed design goal.  it's supposed to be there merely to determine whether or not the post needs further attention, rather than for time to be spent actually dealing with or fixing the post.  Now I see selecting a reason here as an important step and not slowing down the process *too much*, mostly because it's something that really can be done quite quickly.

Comment: Trivia: the difference in the median time-to-review for Unsalvageable vs Should Be Improved is about 7 seconds. Yes, it takes longer - but it's not really enough to impact the speed at which questions move through Triage. That doesn't mean we can't make the flag dialog better though; if it's this annoying for Triagers, it's probably confusing as hell for new users.

Comment: @Shog9: it *is* that annoying for triagers imho.

Answer (score 12):

A reason needs to be selected because where the posts goes when it leaves Triage is going to depend on *why* it's not salvageable.  It might need to got to the close queue, or it might need to go in the mod queue.

Comment: Which might be a valid reason, but then two buttons are more appropriate than a single one: "Unsalvageable / Close" vs "Unsalvageable / Flag". Every time the popup shows up, one ends up interrupting the flow, to the point where one ends up considering skipping the garbage -- which defeats the entire purpose of the queue.

Comment: @Denis The different types of flags, even within those categories, are still processed noticeably differently.  Choosing among them is a part of "getting the post to the right place", which is the goal of triage.  Choosing a close/flag reason is still something that you can do quite quickly; it might not be a single click, but it's still very fast, and within the scope of "categorizing" the post.

Comment: @Denis If you're here just to maximize your review count in as short of a time as possible, and aren't interested in actually helping out the site, then *that* is a problem, and not something that the queue should be designed around.  It's here to help people help the site, not to help people get badges.

Comment: It's still an awkward back and forth with the mouse (or in my case, trackpad). Contrast this with the other two buttons, where it's just click... click... click... Perhaps a dropdown button or something might work better.

Comment: @Denis There's already a discussion on ease of use here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278638/closing-questions-should-be-easier-in-the-triage-queue

Comment: Well, as I wrote in my answer to the original post, I think the whole experiment is bound to fail. Because, as things stand, it's nothing but a new interface for the current front page -- which users are actively avoiding. Still, unsalvageable is unsalvageable; no justification needed during triage imo. Not anymore than a doc would need to diagnose a precise liver injury when triaging a newcomer with a gapping hole in a chest. An unsalvageable queue for others to decide *why* it's trash would make triaging *much* faster than things currently are.

Comment: @Denis It would make it much faster, but it would also make it much less useful.  It wouldn't be directing posts to the correct places, and those places would have a much harder time handling the posts as there wouldn't be any reason for them being there.  Again, the goal here is to help the site, not to maximize the speed of reviewing.  Yes, it's important to make sure this queue isn't *too* slow.  Certain reviews taking 15 seconds instead of 10 is still going to be quite fast.

Comment: Tbh, I'm surprised by the reaction with this post as compared to the duplicate that @davidism just mentioned. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278638/closing-questions-should-be-easier-in-the-triage-queue

Comment: @Denis He's trying to figure out a way to *provide the same information* but with less clicks.  You're saying that people should just *provide less information*.  That's the difference.  Doing the same thing, but easier, is something people can support.  Just not doing it because it takes too long isn't.

Comment: Well, I still fail to see what's wrong with having two separate triage steps: a first queue to triage good, so-so, and bad; and then another two queues to more properly triage so-so and bad.

Comment: @Denis What's wrong with it is that it doesn't add value.  Adding another queue to figure out how bad posts should be flagged isn't improving people's ability to review.  In order to figure out that a post is bad, you'll have already had to figure out why it's bad, so you should be indicating that when choosing that option.  Not doing so would likely end up just adding/duplicating a lot of work.