# Triage: How to vote if more information is needed

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

In triage review queue, I've come across several questions which seem to be suitable for Stack Overflow if the user provided some more information.
Often the question either lacks example code or a suitable debugging stacktrace. Without this information it is not impossible, but probably rather difficult for others to come up with a good answer.

I usually leave a comment which asks for this specific kind of information. But it's not clear how to classify the question:

`Looks good` seems to be wrong.

`Unsalvageable` seems too harsh, since I feel that only a little more information would turn this question to a good one.

But is `Should be improved` the right option? I always hesitate to choose this option since I feel it can only be fixed by the author but not really by edits from the community.

I now tend to skip these questions thinking that a `more information needed from the author` option would be the only right option.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278499/2958086) should help you figure out what to click. In your case, regardless of who needs to provide input, if it needs improvement, it needs improvement.

Comment: @Compass, sorry I did not mean to send that comment. So triage is really about classifying into these broad categories and not about gathering additional information what's wrong with the post?
Following the flow chart I would classify 80% of all posts as `should be improved` and 15% to `unsalvageable`

Comment: If the question can tread water on its own, you don't need to give it inflatable arm thingies. Almost all questions can be improved. But does the question need improvement for it to float, is what I ask myself. If it can sustain and has like 1 or 2 minor typos, I would let a normal 2K user deal with that, rather than sending it through a queue.

Comment: see also: [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing?lq=1)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### The goal for Should Be Improved: a third path for lackluster questions

This observation hits on the intention for Should Be Improved:

> Without this information it is not impossible, but probably rather difficult for others to come up with a good answer.

There are a *lot* of questions that can be (and often are!) answered, but which make writing a *good* answer unnecessarily difficult, either because they make the answerer guess at part of the problem, or because they're just *really hard to read* (grammar, formatting, no summary, etc.)

Strictly-speaking, many of these *can* be closed: "unclear what you're asking" fits. But closing entails a hell of a lot of overhead... And reopening in those cases where the question is edited chews up even more resources from the good folks reviewing these. Worse, if someone does put the time and effort into deciphering the problem and writes up a decent answer before the question is closed... Well, now we've created a situation where we've *guaranteed* that time will be wasted: either those who reviewed and closed the question, or those who took the time to answer it. All for the want of an edit...

If we could just identify such questions *sooner*, it would become possible to do a few things to make this tragic situation less common:

- Show these questions to fewer people until/unless they've been edited.
- Encourage authors to edit
- [Encourage *answerers* to edit](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/)

And this is *exactly* what we're hoping to do with questions triaged as Needs Improvement... That is, *if* this test works and the bulk of the questions falling into that category can be easily salvaged.

That said... It's clear we should be doing a better job of drawing distinctions between these three categories *in the review UI itself*. Ain't nobody got time to read rambling meta posts like this.

### New guidance for Should Be Improved and Unsalvageable

I suspect a big part of the problem here is that we were defining "Unsalvageable" via tautology:

> Unsalvageable for questions that are unsalvageable and should be removed from the site

That's... less than helpful. Which naturally led folks to guessing at it based on what they see when you click the button: [a really verbose flagging dialog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278638/closing-questions-should-be-easier-in-the-triage-queue). Which then brings you to the close dialog, and leads to confusion as to whether all questions that *can* be closed truly *are* unsalvageable. ...Which I already talked about, above.

Let's make this a bit more explicit, by contrasting it with your observation that I quoted above:

> - **Unsalvageable** for questions that cannot or should not be answered and must therefore be removed from the site.

The other source of confusion seems to arise from the description for Should Be Improved, which reads:

> Should Be Improved for questions that would benefit from further revision by the author or others

I see two problems there:

1. Even *good* questions could generally use a bit of copy-editing.
2. There's no criteria for what sorts of edits should be expected here. Typo fixes? Clarification? Complete re-write?

It's probably not a good idea to be *too* explicit here; after all, [this is *intended* to be a grey area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278461/triage-gray-areas-what-should-we-do-when-the-question-is-borderline/278499#278499) between excellent and awful. But we can still try to provide a *little bit* more contrast to the other options:

> - **Should Be Improved** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

These changes will be live after the next build:

[image: preview of changes]

Comment: The new text is far better than the previous one.

Comment: So if a question needs additional information from the author, and the missing information is information that cannot be edited in by anyone else, how does choosing NI work to accomplish that?  What are the reviewers in the NI queue expected to be doing?  How is the author going to know what is expected of them?  How does the post leave that queue after the author does fix the post?

Comment: You can leave a comment if you want, @Servy. Eventually, we'll be feeding these into another queue where reviewers will be asked to provide  either edits or guidance; I'll elaborate on that in a future post. Most importantly though, there's no shortage of information already available on how to ask... If the author wishes more people to see his question.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm simply curious on how the actual NI queue, that posts marked as such get fed into, should handle these posts.  Assuming users in that queue are given options to mark as post as OK, edit, comment, and flag, what should they do when a post doesn't have enough information?  They can comment, but then what?  If they then mark it as OK it'd go to the front page without enough information.  If they vote to close as unclear then there's the issues you've mentioned here.  They'd almost need a button specifically for "wait for author to edit" to press after commenting.

Comment: I'm bringing this up now, before your proposal for NI, because the resolution to this problem may (or may not) be to change triage, not NI.  The longer we wait to make changes in what types of posts get put where in Triage, the harder it will be to change it later.

Comment: Fair enough, @Servy - [let's hash this out in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66501/discussion-on-answer-by-shog9-triage-how-to-vote-if-more-information-is-needed).