# Are there any examples of how to handle questions in the triage queue?

Tags: discussion, triage

I have triaged 11 questions to date but I am not happy that I have chosen correctly. Mostly I have chosen "Should be improved" but that may have been too generous. How should I respond to various questions?

Below are some examples I have just been looking at. It would be useful if the answers to this question included some other questions and guidance on their triage status.

---

> Q: how to make a fancybox for google map?
>
> I just used Google Maps
> Javascript API v3 it works, but the problem is how can I open it in
> fancybox as Booking website  so could anyone help me, please?

This could have code added to show what they have tried, or perhaps they have not tried anything at all yet.

---

> Q: How do I test string data type in vb.net?
>
> I want to test string type in VB.Net, for example. A number plate follows the format 2 letters, 2 numbers, 3 letters.
>
> I want to take the input from a user and by using an IF statement I want to check if the format is correct, if it is not then I want to store it under a variable or output it depending on if they are speeding (my program). So how would I check for a certain amount of numbers and letters in a string?
>
> Thanks, any help is appreciated.

This might be someone asking us to provide all the needed code when they have not tried anything.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278747/2958086

Comment: I looked at the Q&A linked by both @Compass and davidism. It has lots of information but I did not see and real practical guidance on how to choose what to do. What I would like is a short, concise, explanation of how to choose.

Comment: @AdrianHHH how about this flow chart then? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278461/triage-gray-areas-what-should-we-do-when-the-question-is-borderline/278499#278499