# How to triage "waiting for OP to add content" questions?

Tags: discussion, triage

There are many questions like the following 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11201634
which could be good enough but lack details. Some other users commented suggesting the OP to add required missing content (code snippet, configuration fragment, ...).
I would wait for a while (24-48h, ideally) to see whether OP adds missing details or not.

Is "skip" the best option here? I fear that this will simply drop the burden onto next reviewer.

This old question does not seem to anwer my concern:
[Triage: How to vote if more information is needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278735/triage-how-to-vote-if-more-information-is-needed)

Comment: Close it, stop others wasting their time on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a question needs more information before it can be answered, you should not wait to close it. Close it immediately so people don't waste time on it.  The best close reason in this case is

Unsalvageable > Should be closed > Off-topic >

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

There's no good reason for a question to sit open in an unanswerable state for 24 to 48 hours while the OP edits it. They had all the time in the world to edit their question before they posted it. Shut it down as soon as possible so they can get to work on fixing it.

Comment: I always found "unsalvageable" odd in this case: there's still a chance that OP comes back and adds information (salvaging the post). I know this isn't the typical scheme, but still...

Comment: @AndrasDeak - What "unsalvageable" means here is that it is impossible for the rest of the community (anyone other than the OP) to fix it. Posts that only have grammar and formatting errors are salvageable because anyone can fix them.

Comment: @BSMP thanks, that makes much more sense.

Comment: @AndrasDeak BSMP is exactly right. "Unsalvageable" in this context means that the post isn't able to be fixed by the reviewer. Only the original poster can come back and salvage the question by providing the needed information.