# Ability to close some questions directly

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, help-improvement

I had a look into the new queue ([Help Improve The Help & Improvement Queue!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue)) and noticed that there are a lot of questions, which I would consider to close.
There are questions about what recommendation do you give me, how can I do that, why is my code not working and so on ...

The only way to close them at the moment, is to open them and vote for close.
I would like to have below the question the possibility to vote for close directly.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a misunderstanding by most people in how the Triage queue works. "Needs improvement" (which feeds the Help & Improvement queue) is hit far more often than "Unsalvageable". Possibly because the latter requires *at least* two more clicks. >.> (disclaimer: this is unfounded theorising as I have no numbers to support my biased statement)

Comment: So it is more a call for improvement of the Triage queue.

Comment: No reason not to request this feature too. Questions *will* slip through that don't belong in the H&I queue. =)

Comment: I have already seen a request for a button *This doesn't need improvement, it is crap*

Comment: Hum ... To this topic? Then it isn't properly tagged ...

Comment: As one of the many people who requested that button in the original topic, I can say for sure that there are answers there which mention it. I'm pretty sure the top voted one qualifies, actually.

Comment: This is already asked for in the main post about the H&I queue: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue