# The Help & Improvement Queue gives you credit for an edit that did nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, help-improvement

The [new Help & Improvement Queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue) no longer requires a comment along with an edit to a post, which is great.

However, this has introduced a new bug: the queue now no longer requires anything at all to count as a review. You receive credit for an edit that does nothing to the post.
(At least it does not add a revision if nothing was actually changed.)

(If you're curious, I discovered this when I started to edit a post, but realized that there was nothing that I could do and clicked "Save Edits" instead of "cancel.")

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Enter [the H&I review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper).
2. Select the "Edit" option from the top.
3. Scroll to the bottom of the post and click "Save Edits."

An example review for demonstration: https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/7263188

Comment: Yes, this happens , I [confirmed here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/7263188) **PLEASE NO ONE ELSE TRY THIS THOUGH** It works, trust us!

Comment: @Roombatron5000, yes, it happens even today :) Saying NO ONE ELSE TRY THIS usually tend the people to do the opposite.

Comment: Too bad I don't have 2k reputation! Just joking.

Comment: I've seen a couple of questions in this queue that genuinely didn't need any edits -- possibly because other people had already fixed them by the time I got to them, or possibly because the people who tagged it for review didn't understand the question.  An explicit "this is fine as is" button would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next build will enforce the requirements to make a change to an edit before allowing them to be saved from the help and improvement queue.  Thanks for the report.

Comment: If the next build is already live then it is broken. I can't save edits even if a change has been made!

Comment: Sure enough, there's a fix incoming!

Comment: He fixed this by whistling into a modem via a satellite phone, _and_ negotiated [V.32bis](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.32bis-199102-I/en) in the process while standing right next to the code open on his machine, because that's just how he rolls.

Comment: Fix deployed - the help and improvement queue is back on. @DavidPostill