# Help & Improvement queue gives page not found error

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, help-improvement

While trying to reach [The Help & Improvement Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) as per the link in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue) gives page not found error. It also doesn't show in the list on the 
[review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

The [statistics for this queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/stats) can still be reached.

Comment: Confirmed. Now the big question, intended or actually a bug?

Comment: Appears resolved for me now, though I was seeing the issue a few minutes ago.

Comment: Queue has made a comeback! Was hoping for some more options like `Unable to Improve - Requires More Detail` or `No Improvement Necessary`, but alas.

Comment: It was broken. See [The Help & Improvement Queue gives you credit for an edit that did nothing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287685)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had it turned off for a bit while we fixed some bugs.  It should be on again!

Comment: Yes it is back online.