# Can we add a tag filter option to the Help & Improvement review queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some queues have a filter option that allow reviewers to only review items related to specific tags. For example, the First Posts review queue has one:

[image: First Posts review queue tag filter]

I feel most comfortable improving questions about technologies that I have a decent handle on, and I would like to focus on those questions. I skip a lot of the questions in the queue if I don't understand the technologies because I find myself asking questions like the following:

- Is that a misspelled acronym or just one I haven't seen before?
- Is that improperly formatted code that's making this hard to read or a strange but idiomatic construct?
- If I knew the technology better, would I be able to find a question in the blocks of text full of terms I don't understand?

I know that there is an inherent risk in improving questions in a subject area I know well: it could be easy to accidentally make assumptions about the asker's intent since I understand the subject better. However, that risk is already there since I can already come across questions in subject areas I understand well. I don't think implementing this feature request would increase that risk.

I think I could complete improvements faster and more accurately if I could focus on my preferred technologies, and thus request a tag filter for the Help & Improvement review queue.

Comment: This has already been suggested in the duplicate. Its planned, they just haven't done it yet :) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287501/1783619

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You are correct. I didn't see that buried a couple of answers deep. Thanks!

Comment: @skrrgwasme I'm also waiting :D http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue/287501#comment162482_287466