# Allow review queues to be easily filtered by "my answer tags"

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, filtering

I'd like to have the ability for a reviewer to filter review queues based on "my answer tags" with some simple GUI toggle action.

Review queue filtering has been discussed before:

- [Help Improve The Help & Improvement Queue!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue)
- [Can we add a tag filter option to the Help & Improvement review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287700/can-we-add-a-tag-filter-option-to-the-help-improvement-review-queue)
- [Filter review queue by default](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309583/filter-review-queue-by-default)

but this feature request is different from those previous discussions because it's *specific to using **"my answer tags"** as the queue filter*.

Rationale:

1. The current filter has a "3 tag limit".

   - A "3 tag limit" means the reviewer needs spend time on pondering and fiddling with just which 3 tags to use.
   - A "3 tag limit" likely does not fully represent the scope of the reviewers expertise and interests.
2. The tags on "my answers" represent topics where the reviewer has some confidence for providing answers.
3. Use of "my answer tags" filter can dynamically update with tags based on topics the reviewer has recently anwered.
4. Finally, a dynamic "my answer tags" filter could even sunset (not use) tags the reviewer has not used in answers for the last 2-3 or more years.

**Basically, when a reviewer has enough confidence to post an answer as a user, then these answer tags disclose the reviewer's areas of expertise and interest.**

Comment: Very related: [Could a review items be filtered by favorite tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262383/could-a-review-items-be-filtered-by-favorite-tags), and probably easier to define/maintain than "my answer tags". Still, I think this would be a very good idea, and should arguably be done by default.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading something that suggested that having more than 3 tags in the filter may cause performance issues. I can't find the link though.

Comment: Even if there's a performance issue on more than 3, using your top 3 tags doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: AFAIK, the queue kind of offer you what guesses its the best post if you *don't use filters* based on your past behavior... I vaguely remember being Shog who said it.

Comment: @Braiam Then why in the heck do I see iOS and PHP questions when I get into the review queue? I've never gone anywhere *near* Apple product questions, and I don't have to deal with PHP, either. If it tries to, it certainly seems to fail.

Comment: @jpmc26 it just "kind of", in the sense of trying to show you first those.

Comment: Similar suggestion at the end of this answer. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351503/5779732