# How to handle useless improvements in the new "Help and Improvement" queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, help-improvement

Now that the [Help and Improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue) queue launched, I'm wondering how low-quality reviews are handled.

I took a few example to illustrate the problem:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Please note I don't want to blame reviews' authors, but I would like to know what happens to these posts. There were first sorted in the `Needs improvement`, and arrived in `Help and Improvement` queue. Now, they leave this queue **in an almost similar state** than before.

Unfortunately, the golden badge race seems to drastically reduce the quality of these reviews. If reviewers feel these posts **need** improvements, there is every chance that it requires something *more* than typo correction, or text moves.

Could there be a way to be more strict on these reviews?

Comment: Hmm, this queue was [pretty widely panned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue), reviewers just don't stand much of a chance to help.

Comment: [My proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278382/1159478) from way back when Triage was announced was to have completed reviews go back to Triage.  Triage can them mark the post as NI if it still needs improvement.  If a large percentage of a user's reviews are pushed back into NI by Triage, you know that that user is regularly making insufficient edits.

Comment: ... or he has really rotten luck in getting reviewed. As SO is quite big, and depending on the number of reviews considered, that could actually happen in rare cases.

Comment: @Deduplicator It'll certainly be the case that a good reviewer will have a certain number of items pushed back, due to improper triage reviews, or simply not noticing problems here or there (or say by the OP rolling back the edits, introducing new problems, etc.)  But if the percentage becomes sufficiently large, odds are they're doing something wrong.  Of course, if needed, it can just be an automatic mod flag rather than automatic suspension, to allow for that human touch to see if the reviewer really is the one with the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few things going on around this, the first of which is a feedback loop we're inserting that takes questions edited through the queue, but moved *nowhere* subsequently, and tosses them back in. They were edited, but for some reason, those edits didn't result in the activity we hoped for on the question.

Sometimes, this can just be a case of a very niche tag, or just a rather difficult question, but in either case folks are neither voting on it nor answering it presumably because they can't quite understand it.

The second is rolling out a set of badges, bronze silver and gold, which are awarded based on how questions you've edited in the queue fared after you edited.

If:

- You were the only editor *from the queue* to touch a question and
- It receives at least one up vote, two answers, and one up vote to either answer
- It isn't closed for any reason other than being a duplicate
- (criteria still under construction)

.. you get a badge, probably bronze, which can be awarded multiple times. We'll take gold and silver from there, and probably associate some privileges with earning them. Still on the drawing board, I'm just mentioning it because we're looking at various ways to provide incentive for more substantial edits. You won't get these badges just for editing. Your edits actually need to *count* and make the post go on to a brighter future than it would have without your help.

These also help folks stay motivated. It will be nice to get notice of a badge in your inbox, and then go on to discover that a question you worked hard on last week now has a score of +5 and a few great answers. We'll still keep the usual per-queue badges, but those will be pretty dull looking in comparison to the new badges I've got planned.

The other thing I want to do is more strongly encourage substantial edits in the editor. That's why it's guided the way that it is, and the original design actually forced you to change at least 2 out of 4 things before you could save it. That was dropped because we don't want to get in the way of good editors. I don't think we're surfacing the guidance there well enough - it needs to be stronger if nothing is actually *making* folks look at it.

Now, the flip side -

You've made .. let's say .. 40 edits. Less than 1:10 of them qualified you for the new bronze badge - that's *not* a particularly impressive amount, and it could be that this queue might not be for you. We're not doing it yet, but once the dust settles, I'm going to be keeping a *very* close eye on it. I might bring back 'force you to touch at least 2/4' in the interface for folks that don't have a very good success rate, up to (possibly) letting some know that this queue just isn't for them. But I don't want to commit to anything without more data.

From what we've seen, now that folks can see the triage and helper queues working together, the grand scheme of things has become much clearer. Priority 1 is now completing the features missing from the queue itself, which we've been rolling out the last few days.

tl;dr; we anticipated this, and it's under review. Before we go changing *too* much, we want to see how folks settle into it. But, at least you know what's planned, and some contingencies if they're needed.

Comment: For serious reviewers, the H&I queue is the most labor-intensive queue. Meanwhile I see lazy reviewers making the smallest edits just to get their badge. To them it's a numbers game. Demanding that an improved question gets answers and upvotes won't change that - it'll just mean that the numbers got bigger. Worse, they'll stick around after getting their Steward badges, making the most trivial edits until sheer numbers will give them the new badges as well. The 2/4 might help here, but I'm afraid we'll need a lot more than that.