# Upvoting comments shown in the Help and Improvement review queue

Tags: feature-request, help-improvement

I asked to show the comments while editing a post from the the Help & Improvement queue in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287588/1307905). That was implemented, so you can see other comments. But you cannot upvote any of the comments shown there although the upvote arrow is shown next to the comment.

I can understand if there are problems to allow the upvoting of comments from that page, so if implementing that is not possible, can the upvote arrow be removed from the comments presented on that page?

I only later noticed that the other comments are shown when the option to vote on the question is presented (after editing is done). There **you can** upvote the comments.