# Editing a question in the "Help and Improvement" queue should not post the edit summary as a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, help-improvement

When editing on the *"Help and Improvement"* queue, the comment box adds to both the edit summary *and* explicitly adds a comment under the post.

Duplicating the message like this is unnecessary and inappropriate. The edit summary should be the sole place of record for explanations regarding edits. This  type of information does not belong in the comments and is just noise when it appears there.

- Edit descriptions tend to be brief, unstructured, abbreviated, etc., which do not make for good comments.
- Most edits speak for themselves, and no further commentary is required.
- Comments should be *actionable*: they should provide suggestions on how to improve the posts. An edit does not require any action; the improvements have already been made.
- Edit summaries are generally only useful to the original poster—for everyone else viewing the post, this information is just fluff.

The decision to leave a comment should be separate from the decision to edit. The edit description should not be simply echoed as a comment. We all know where the comment button is if further clarification is required.

Comment: I half expected a comment to have come with Cody Gray's edit containing a summary of the edit, but alas it wasn't so. I've never a fan of any form of automated comments, but edit summaries is just straight up noise imo.

Comment: @Remy Only edits made through the "Help and Improvement" review queue automatically post the edit summary as a comment. No other interface for editing does this. That's precisely why I'm convinced that this is a bug.

Comment: @CodyGray I am aware that it only happens for edits through "Help and Improvement", it was more intended as a bit of a joke, and that it would serve a good purpose of showing how useless it is to have (if it would be something deliberate) ^^

Comment: @CodyGray "We ask you to explain why you edited the way that you did **in a comment that will be left on the question and copied to the edit summary**. This is your opportunity to teach someone the fine nuances of asking questions by mentioning how a clear and descriptive title will help them get better answers sooner. Don't worry, we provide some examples." https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287466/792066 [tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: We're revisiting this. We're actively looking at queues right now and going to look into this as part of that work. Will update here with more as we get to it.

Comment: Just turn off the posting of a comment, @Jon. This is causing a lot of disruption. Moderators have already contacted a user *twice* to ask them to stop generating this level of noise, and both times the user has had to explain that it is not their fault, that the system is automatically posting these comments when they try to improve people's posts. I appreciate that you're doing a major overhaul of the review queues, and that's great. But this doesn't need to be rolled into that because we don't want to wait another 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @CodyGray just to prove that you're not to set the priorities it got fixed just past the 8 weeks mark. But it got fixed, so it is a win!

Answer (score 16):

Providing guidance to the asker through comments was a nice idea. It's unfortunate that it didn't work out in practice.

As of a few minutes ago, edits made through the Help & Improvement queue will ask for an edit summary just like edits made in the other queues or directly on the post, and these summaries won't be posted as comments.

Comment: Good work! I shall be more inclined to leave summary comments, now.

Comment: [Shog9's post at time of launch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287477) deserves to be linked, what a gem :)