# What's to be edited in the Help and Improvement review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, help-improvement

I have been reviewing posts and I love to help the community as much as I can. I just got access to a couple of new review queues, but I am not sure how to help:

> **Help and Improvement**
>
> **Edit** if you understand this question well enough to give it clear, attractive language and formatting
>
> **Skip** if you don't feel there's anything you can do to help this question or its author

Most of the time I don't know what to do, so I just skip. However, I was wondering what kind of edits I should make. I clearly do not want to change the intent of the person asking the question.

Comment: You should be editing the post such that after your edit it is a quality, clear, well formatted, understandable, on topic, appropriately scoped, etc. question.  If you don't know how to do that, then that's fine (it's certainly not easy) just stick to other queues that are more straightforward.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue

Comment: Thanks you @NathanOliver I will check out that link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first suggest that you look back at your past reviews (such as [this low quality review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7620108)) and consider the expected quality of posts.  You should be making the same edits in help and improvement that you would in other queues... but offering *more* guidance as to why you are making these edits.

For example, [this first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7621980) needs some action and should be improved (and consideration if it is even on topic for Stack Overflow - or if it is high enough quality that it should be flagged for migration to another stack exchange site). If you feel that no action is needed on posts of this quality, I am not sure that you should be delving into the Help and Improvement queue too far.

You should make sure the post is well written, well formatted, clear. If English is not your primary language or you use it in an informal way (making use of 'i' rather than 'I' and not starting the sentence with a capital letter), I would *strongly* suggest sending the text of the question you are looking at through an online grammar checker such as [Spell Check Plus](http://spellcheckplus.com/) which can help you with identifying various things to fix.  If [someone else is apologizing for the poor English](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7613583), correct it.

The resulting question should be written as if it was done by a competent technical writer. Colloquialisms and other informalities should not be present in the question.  The first part of the question should clearly identify the problem (as it is the summary for the question that is shown on the front page).  The title should match the body (or vice versa) and the tags should be appropriate.