# Inconsistent UI in review-bar Element in Different Review Queues

Tags: bug, help-improvement

The UI element in question here is this (as well as variations thereof, including when it contains buttons)

[image]

On some review queues, this element - which has the class `review-bar` - acts as a sticky element when you scroll down the page. Technically speaking, it goes from `position: static` to `position: fixed`.

The only problem with this is that it seems to be inconsistent across the different queues.

Take for instance [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/) and [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/). The "sticky" behavior only happens in the latter.

After some more investigation it appears that the only queue without the sticky review-bar is in fact Help and Improvement.

Is this by design of this specific queue? Or is it a bug?

Comment: I have a vague memory that this is deliberate, to facilitate highly contextual editing without having to worry about the bar getting in the way.

Comment: Yeah that's sorta what I was thinking. Makes sense

Comment: [Link with Shog9 comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287490/4099598).