# Where are the posts in "Help and Improvement" from? What actions are expected to do?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, help-improvement

I'm making all kinds of reviews in a long time.

And now I'm working on the "Help and Improvement" queue.

After a period of reviewing, I found that I can rarely make some really good improvement on the post.

I think about it, and guess the reasons are:

- I'm not familiar with the problem in the queue.
- The problem is sometimes not understandable enough.
- The problem is too low quality.
- Action on the post can make little change, which have no improvement at all.

Also, the queue do not usually has a lot of posts. So I'm even doubt about the rule itself:

- What do the queue posts come from? Do that means the problem is meaningful, but still needs improvement?
- Is editing a good way to help and improve? What do the community what us to do when making review actions?

Comment: Did you already read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287466/2675154)?