# I was blocked from reviewing: How are questions marked as spam on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, triage, review-suspension

I marked a question in review as *requires editing* and got a response saying it was spam.

I put in some time to view the question before answering and to me it looked like it requires editing. Is there a way for me to make an appeal to get unblocked if I am not wrong here?

Question Title:

> trouble with debugging in Charles Proxy

The Question:

> Hi :) I am trying to debug a file on the website www.stardoll.com with Charles Proxy. I am activating breakpoints so I can edit the request of saveChat.php but when I click execute the response always returns FALSE as you can see in the images below :
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> But when I erase the values of _ aId _I and _xt the response returns true.. How can I do that on my own site? Not allow the user to edit the request? Thanks :)

This is what showed up when I pressed the review button:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11153800.
>   Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing.

I know what [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) is now, have seen people use it for testing. Don't think that this had to be spam. Don't think this had to be closed either. I guess even the user got deleted/blocked on this, which is unfair. But who cares. RIP "trouble with debugging in Charles Proxy".

Comment: Are you sure that question "Requires Editing"? What kind of "editing" you think it merits?

Comment: @Braiam Could I call it spam. What would be an appropriate review here?

Comment: You tell me. You said it required editing. What kind of editing were you expecting so other folks can answer this question?

Comment: @Braiam At least the images could be added in the question instead of links and may be some more explanation could be added who ever knows Charles

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Right there. That's not a responsibility of anyone else but OP to explain their problem clearly. Not someone else. Don't make your peers waste their times with this kind of questions. Unsalvageable -> Off Topic -> No MCVE is the way to go.

Comment: @Braiam Ok . It says that the post was marked spam. Wasn't it also closed for the wrong reason. See I had flagged other questions as unsalvagable before saying they were unclear or low quality which were similar to this. So to me this question is very confusing to be reviewed. I think there would be different perspectives for different people.

Comment: Yes, that post was closed erroneously.  And it also did kind of have enough info to be answered.

Comment: @BrockAdams  . It seems on the very edge of unsalvagable and requires editing. I forgot to mention previously the flags to similar questions were declined for me.

Comment: The question links to non-programming site. Why are you sure that it *isn't* spam?

Comment: That didn't require editing, it required a rework from the OP.  Poor formatting would require editing.  Poor asking requires the OP add what the question is missing.  That might be a point of confusion.  Yes, the OP needed to edit it, but that isn't the same as "Requires Editing."  At least that's my interpretation; someone from the team might clarify.

Comment: @Will: That's the interpretation put forward in the [faq-proposed for Triage](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-triage/295674#295674) that I drafted. 80 upvotes later, I think it's a general consensus.

Comment: @NathanTuggy wut, I was right? Lawks!

Comment: @Will: Seems you do manage the occasional spot of brilliance! :P

Comment: Since no-one said it. You weren't blocked from reviewing because of that particular audit. You were blocked because you made several previous audit errors. Don't focus one that one but on all of those that lead to this.

Comment: Even if you made all the edits that the OP should have included in that post to begin with upfront I'd almost certainly *still* be closing it as *"OT: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"*. That's what makes it unsalvageable in my view. (It's not spam however, it's pretty rare for links to the SO imgur site to be spam)

Comment: @Braiam - Wait a minute, you mean the 'Requires Editing' flag doesn't include the OP as a potential editor? Every time I click 'Requires Editing' this is who I have in mind as the person who should be doing the editing...

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland the OP had all the time in the universe up to the point where they hit "post question" to make edits. "Requires editing" pushes the post to http://stackoverflow.com/review/helper where other, experienced users are meant to be able to fix it up into a decent question. *["remember, questions in this queue have been selected because enough people thought they showed strong potential, but needed some work"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue)*

Comment: just stay out of the LQPRQ, I got a 24 hour ban for a single "bad" review that I completely disagreed with as well. The ban rules are broken, they are way too subjective, so last time I even click on that queue since it banned me from reviewing any of the other queues as well.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland [no](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/792066)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson we are talking about triage, not the LQPRQ.

Comment: @Braiam - that queue is a minefield of subjectivity as well, not as bad, but still not worth risking not being able to review because your opinion is slightly more rigorous than someone else's.

Comment: Thanks @Braiam - I think this could be clearer on the Triage page but have raised my concerns on the page you linked to.

Comment: Why are you assuming Charles Proxy must have been the spam-worthy link, when there's another website involved? (A la @BSMP's comment from a year and a half ago.)

Comment: I suppose I should have been more specific in my original comment: Why were you sure that star doll site was OK? Had you checked that one too?

Comment: @BSMP He is trying to ask a debugging question referencing to something he was trying with charles on another site, whether it was possible to do that for him on his own. Do you mean to say based on the site that a person is trying to work on we should judge a post. He is not marketing something on SO nor is he trying to post something vague. I'm sorry , try not to be hurt, and debate something logical. Its ok, if we remove the I from ourselves and concentrate on being good for a change, don't need to be saying I said something in this regard, manipulating our conscience to be right always.

Comment: *Do you mean to say based on the site that a person is trying to work on we should judge a post.* Yes. A link that opens something spammy, malicious, or pornographic shouldn't be allowed in posts here. People do post otherwise reasonable questions with links to those types of sites. Not often, but it does happen. Just because the rest of the question looks OK doesn't mean that all of the URLs in it are legitimate.

Comment: @BSMP Its not a porn site, nor it is malicious. Its a simple dress up game site for girls(kids). I don't know what you're talking about, where you're going at. Anyways its fine. Cheer up.

Comment: I asked "Why were you sure that star doll site was OK? Had you checked that one too?" because it wasn't clear whether you knew what was at that URL.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I preferred to keep the question original as posted by the OP in the triage review. I just felt it required editing for the images and didn't think of it as spam.

Comment: @AkshayHazari: Ah, your quote formatting was unclear, since the actual image URLs were outside the quote entirely, which made it look like you were, for some reason, artificially providing them separately.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'd say this one is quite a good audit actually, because it highlights an important distinction between "requires editing" and "unsalvagable":

It's true that this post does need editing, but that belies the fact that there are more significant, fundamental problems with the question. Even if the most skilled editor on the site hammered it into shape to the best of their ability the question still wouldn't have enough information for an average or probably even skilled user to reproduce the issue it pertains to.

What you've got to remember in triage is that **"requires editing" asks another 2K user to have a go at editing it**. Not the OP (who has already had all the time in the universe to include info/test cases), but *another user*. "Requires editing" pushes the post to https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper where other, experienced users are meant to be able to fix it up into a decent question.

> *["remember, questions in this queue have been selected because enough people thought they showed **strong** potential, but needed some work"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue)*

(emphasis mine)

In set theoretic terms "requires editing" has a large intersection with "unsalvageable". Where the Q could be a member of both sets "unsalvageable" should take precedence because asking an editor to invest time is asking an editor to waste their time.

Based on the comments on this Q it looks like there might be a problem here. In my view that's not an issue with the review bans system (which actually seems to have picked a great audit), but with the information and guidance given to reviewers in this queue.

Comment: Yes, this! Can someone please, please make this more visible for users of the triage queue? Still the usage of *Requires editing* is not clear to many reviewers - Instead of blaming the stupidity of the reviewers, we might as well try to make it as easy as possible for them to get guides on how to review correctly.

Comment: It would also help if questions in *Requires Editing* had an option of "This question should be closed and whoever sent this question here should be reeducated."  Flagging it as VLQ is usually not correct.

Comment: That's an interesting use of the the word "remember" in the sentence that begins *"What you've got to remember in triage..."*, given that there's no reason to think that the OP has forgotten anything. I guess that "remember" must have a complicated alternate form I've never encountered which means *have learned by reading Meta (because this flatly contradicts the guidance in the UI which is very explicit that "Requires Editing" is the correct choice for questions that can be edited into shape by the author and that "Unsalvageable" is only for questions which "must" be removed from the site)*.

Comment: (Of course, I recognise that Flexo notes this very point in the final paragraph of his answer. It's a great shame that nothing has been done to fix this in the year and a half since.)

Answer (score 9):

Audits and review bans are the only automated way the site has to review and instruct reviewers.  So the best approach to this is to learn from it, as we all do every time we review review bans.

Essentially, if a post has a problem statement and an attempt to provide the information needed to make the question answerable, but it may have formatting problems or rewording for clarity, and it can be edited by the community to be on topic for the site, then this is an editable post.

If the question gives a clear problem statement and none of the details needed to reproduce it, there is no amount of editing by the community that can fix it.

Comment: Right. "Close as unclear" and let OP do the editing.

Answer (score -19):

The same thing happens to me time to time. If you haven't made many mistakes, you can get a 2 day ban. If you have made more, you get week. Not a big deal.

Comment: You are not answering the question! -1, read the question properly.

Comment: If you are getting review bans regularly, it's not okay...

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't get them that regularly, but once in awhile I don't fully read whatever. Something like, there's a question hidden in a bunch of run-won sentence. Occasionally I even hit the wrong flag.