# Why am I banned for a failed test, when there was no test?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, review-suspension

This looks like a bug.[image]
[The post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13336577) is "on hold" for some reason. I can't see why. I said it "Looks OK", just like several others did.

However, I was banned for a *week* on this puppy.

What the heck is up with this?

By the way, week-long bans are counter-productive. In my case, I just forget about reviewing, and it ends up being a lot longer. The only reason I review is to be a good citizen here. It's work. It isn't fun, and I don't mind skipping it.

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted so much. Another user was banned for the same review item, and [his meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332542/why-could-reviewing-questions-with-unobvious-belonging-be-a-reason-for-banning-f) was well received. It even sparked a feature request to make the review description more clear: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues.

Comment: @user000001 There's a pretty big difference in tone and apparent intent between that post and this one. One expresses confusion and a willingness to learn, and it contains a focused question on what is on- versus off-topic. The other is a "bug report" with an angry, flippant tone and seems to reject the possibility that there is anything to be learned from the situation. The former tends to get a much better reception than the latter.

Comment: @user000001 I didn't look into the message but on the roaring title alone  I already didn't expect to find a constructive discussion and I was right...

Comment: @EdCottrell: That's true, but I still think that we should be a bit more grateful to the people that try to help moderate the site through the review queues, even if they make an occasional mistake here and there.

Comment: @user000001 I can't speak for everyone here, but I think the problem is that the downvoters *are* grateful to people who try to help moderate the site through the review queues, but *don't* appreciate anger and questions with relatively obvious answers. OP wrote, "The post is 'on hold' for some reason. I can't see why," even though the hold message explains exactly why the question is on hold. In other words, the downvotes are probably a response to the "don't help me, I'll help you" tone and the lack of effort put into the question.

Comment: @user000001 We should be grateful to people doing a *good job* of reviewing and who are *improving* the site with their reviews.  Being grateful to people not reviewing properly, and not willing to learn how to review properly, doesn't seem warranted.

Comment: I edited out the caps, and the post reads a lot more constructively. Might be worth re-reading if you downvoted the first time through. Also, the message doesn't specify a test, so your title is semi incorrect given that the mod flagged you

Answer (score 28):

The "on hold" message is perfectly clear: that question is off-topic. The question really is about server administration, so it really is off-topic, and "Looks OK" was definitely the wrong choice.

Also, you weren't banned automatically by the system. You were banned by a moderator who saw that you were reviewing posts incorrectly.

In short, this isn't a bug; it's user (reviewer) error.

Comment: Oooookaaaay...if you say so. I admit that I did not review the question as pertaining to being "on-topic" for the board (which can be a VERY fuzzy area on these various sites). However, it's just easier for me to stop reviewing. Not a big loss for me.

Comment: @MAGNAWS We're happy to have your help reviewing; it's best if everyone pitches in. But we do ask that you apply the site's rules when reviewing. If you do reviews without worrying about whether or not something is on-topic, you're not helping; you're hurting.

Comment: No prob. I'm a bad reviewer, so I'll stop, and leave it to the experts. I'll see if there's anything else I can do to help out. I can mop the floors and clean the toilets. I do tend to have quite a few distractions on my plate, so I'll admit to not "giving this my 100%." A lot of other folks are almost obsessive about their SO membership. I'm not. I don't especially care that much, but this site is extremely useful, and I'm grateful it's here. Cheers.

Comment: @MAGNAWS Be aware that you can always skip when you are not completely sure about how to review something.