# Wrong review: Requires Editing

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I got this message:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12845648

But what was wrong with that review? It even has been edited since my review.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316295/168175 contains my thoughts on this subject

Answer (score 25, accepted):

'Requires editing' means that the *community* can edit the question to make it a good one. It does *not* mean that the poster him/herself could make the edits, because *every* bad question could be edited. 'Unsalvageable' would be the correct option - see the [Triage review guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue).

You might have been thrown off guard by the explanation for 'Requires Editing'; it still mentions *the author* as one of the possible editors:

> **Requires Editing** for questions where edits by *the author* or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

Comment: so shouldn't that explanation be updated?

Comment: @RomCoo [yes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing).

Comment: My goodness, I've been doing the same thing sometimes because it said 'the author'. The fact that _three people_ said 'requires editing' on this post should indicate there's something needing changing in that explanation!

Comment: It's a "nice" ambiguity that ought to be improved - the subtlety is in the difference between the author being the only one who could fix it and the author being one of many who could fix it.  The latter reading was the intended meaning I believe.

Comment: Perhaps it should be updated to "for questions where edits by the community would result ...".  The author is included in the community and would make it clear what is meant.

Answer (score 5):

That post has serious problems; well beyond what the community is capable of fixing through editing.  You should have marked it as unsalvageable.