# Replace "Requires Editing" button text with "Needs help"

Tags: feature-request, triage

TL;DR Let's put "Needs Help" on that button instead of "Requires Editing".

---

In Triage, reviewers have three options: <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd>, <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> and <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>.

<kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> means that users other than the OP can improve the question to make it a good fit for the site. It sends the question to the Help & Improvement queue.

However, Triage reviewers keep clicking <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> on things that can only be improved by the OP. These should be marked as <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> instead, so that they get put "On Hold" - which is our signal to an OP that they need to improve their question.

As a few cases to illustrate the point, check [this MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344505/812149) or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327197/812149) where reviewers misinterpreted the button. Or [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346052/812149) about the Unsalvageable questions that ended up in H&I due to wrong Triage reviewing.

The guidance text that clarifies how to review in Triage is linked from that queue. But that hasn't helped - or at least it hasn't helped enough. I'm not convinced people actually follow the link before reviewing.

So, we need to make it more immediately clear that "Requires Editing" means a post can be edited *by someone other than the OP*.

For this purpose, I propose that we change the text on the button. Instead of <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd>, the button should say <kbd>Needs help</kbd>.

"Help" is, almost by definition, something that only other parties can provide. With this small change, it should be more clear to Triage reviewers when to choose that button.

Comment: The naming is still confusing. Nothing is ever "Unsalvageable" as long as it is editable. The queues still lack guidance IMHO; a lot of the misuse seems to come from users who've never been properly introduced to the guidelines of reviewing. So instead of just renaming the buttons, provide better guidance for reviewers. Of course, for starters, the buttons could be named `Asker must clarify` and `Someone needs to format this`.

Comment: @CodeCaster The Triage queue has a link to the guidance, people don't seem to read it though. I'd be in favor of "Asker must clarify", but I guess SO wants to keep the text as short as possible.

Comment: I feel like this feature-request to [add a review queue tutorial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336206/6214222) (which you have also given an answer to) would be the best thing we could do right now. Especially for the Triage queue, where most reviewing jobs are absolute garbage. Not only do way too many reviewers click on *requires editing* when the question is unsalvageable but there are quite a lot that say *looks okay*. These people should either not be reviewing at all or they should at least get an obligatory tutorial to understand how the review works.

Comment: This almost puts us back to *should be improvement* that also did not work and was changed to *requires editing*.  I think we need to get that [guidance fixed in the queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing) first.

Comment: @NathanOliver I upvoted that feature request long ago... can't believe the wrong guidance is **still** there!! :-(  But I think "Should be improved" can be easily interpreted as "OP should improve it". "Needs help" was the shortest  text I could think of, that would convey that the improvement could be made by someone other than the OP.

Comment: What about *requires/needs community edit*?

Comment: @NathanOliver That could work, too. I just hope people won't interpret that as "needs editing by the Community bot", or something like that.

Comment: In addition to updating the guidance text that shows when you click on *more* we should also update the text you see when hovering over the *requires editing* button. Both should include something along the lines of "users **other than the OP** can fix this question" (including the emphasis), just so there won't be any room for misinterpretation. I could imagine that most reviewers currently do actually read the text that shows when hovering the buttons (especially if the button name were to change as well).

Comment: Another option is: "Needs editing by other users" - albeit a bit long. "Needs help" is really unclear. What kind of help? Mental help? Help in answering the question? People might start clicking this button for a bunch of reasons.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Good point. I'd like to keep the word "help" in there because it implies that others than the OP are needed. But maybe there is a better word for that. I think the text needs to be short, for UX reasons.

Answer (score 2):

When you click the more link above the review buttons in the help queue, you see text including the following:

- Requires Editing for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

I understand that the guide is also linked, but if you don't want reviewers  to click needs editing when only the OP can fix the question, then that help text also needs to be corrected.
I think that change, rather than changing the button label is the change most likely to improve the situation.
For me as a reviewer, changing the button label to "needs help" would re-enforce the idea that I should click that button if only the OP can revise the question.

When I first started reviewing, I thought "needs editing" meant that the question needed editing by people other than the OP.  I eventually got to a question where I wasn't sure what to do and clicked  the more button.  Based on that guidance I clicked needs editing when the OP could fix questions for about a week.  However, I couldn't imagine that produced  a reasonable work flow.  I imagined that as my reputation increased I'd eventually get access to the queue where all these questions were going and would not be able to do anything with some of the questions I was sending there.  So, I decided to check the guidance again to make sure I read it correctly.  This time I found the guide.  With your proposed button label change, I would have had high enough confidence I never would have looked for the guide

Comment: Definitely. That is a [separate feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321895/812149). Please vote it up, if you haven't already.

Comment: As a long-time user, who tries to help out with triaging every now and then, I thought I knew what the buttons meant after a several months delay, so I didn't re-read the instructions until after I tagged a few posts incorrectly (and I can't even go back and undo this!). The button label definitely must be unambiguous if we expect users who are not doing triage regularly to be of help.