# Reputation by editing from "Help and Improvement" review queue

Tags: support, edits, reputation, help-improvement

I just reached 2,000 reputation, and have unlocked "Help and Improvement".
I edited some questions and I have the impression that these edits do not work as usual: no reputation is gained.

I read [**this topic**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue), but didn't find any answer.

---

Can I earn reputation by reviewing and editing posts from "**Help and Improvement**" review queue?

Comment: You don't get rep on edits after 2k

Comment: You don't get reputation for editing questions and answers after 2k reputation.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. You have access to the queue from 2000 reputation, but from that exact moment, your [edits don't need to be approved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and you don't gain reputation from them anymore. The whole point of the Help & Improvement queue is to edit mediocre questions; it doesn't make sense for the edits done there to be reviewed *again*.