# Is there a limit to how many times a question can get sent back to Triage from H&I?

Tags: support, triage, help-improvement

I *suspect* this is a duplicate but I haven't been able to find anything.

This is in regards to the "Low Quality" link from H&I, and this section in [Shog's nice flowchart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/616460):

[image]

Is there a limit to the number of times a question can return to Triage from H&I (following the loop in that diagram)? If so, what happens when the limit is exceeded and "Low Quality" is clicked in H&I, is it just thrown to the Close Review queue?

The reason I ask is because when I come across categorically unsalvageable questions that made it to H&I from Triage, and I send them back to Triage, I imagine the possibility of them getting stuck in an endless loop if nobody ever explicitly ejects them from the loop by marking Unsalvageable in Triage (discussions of *why* this may happen are [ongoing elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288779/rephrase-triage-help-text-for-should-be-improved-and-unsalvageable)).

Comment: relevant comment https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link#comment168515_288387

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's actually *two* feedback loops in place now (or will be shortly).

The first is the VLQ flag that puts something from the helper queue back into Triage.

The second is something that runs to check for posts that came out of the helper queue, and subsequently went *nowhere*, then puts them back in the helper queue. By nowhere, I mean no up votes, no down votes, barely a few more views - just no activity. Crickets.

In both cases, it's only a matter of a few days normally until a question is no longer eligible to go back to either queue, so that in itself breaks the feedback loop. That's *for now*.

If you haven't noticed, the helper queue tends to have (at any given time) *at most* 30 - 50 questions in it. It's cleared like crazy, way beyond our expectations and for tag filtering to really work as intended there, we need more posts going in. We have some more data to gather, but we *might* be increasing the window that would permit posts into either queue. If we do that, *then* we might look at a more deliberate means of breaking the feedback loops.

But for now, it's not really needed, because things age out quickly enough.

Comment: When something "ages out" of eligibility for the queues, does it then become fully visible? And if it's _then_ flagged VLQ, what happens? Does it in fact go to Triage anyways?