# How does a post reach the Help and Improvement queue?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, triage, help-improvement

I'm trying to understand the whole work-flow of following review queues:

1. Triage
2. Help and Improvement
3. Low Quality Posts

Is a post likely to follow the above mentioned queue life-cycle in the serial order I've mentioned? e.g. Let's say it first comes for Triage. Then somebody marks it as "Requires Editing". So it goes to Help and Improvement queue. When that post reaches "Help and Improvement" queue then someone marks it as "question is very low quality" so it will go to "Low Quality Posts" queue.

Also when I mark a post as "Unsalvageable" in Triage queue, will it go to "Low Quality Posts" queue? How does a post reach to Triage review queue? Is it due to some action taken by an SO user, e.g. flagging?

Comment: According to [the flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjvml.png), flagging VLQ in H&I puts the question back into Triage.  And yes, unless the developers have changed this, it can be sent back into H&I, then back to Triage and so on.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom afaik, there's some safe wards that prevent the question from going into a endless buckle.

Comment: Related question (about the back & forth) [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289749/is-there-a-limit-to-how-many-times-a-question-can-get-sent-back-to-triage-from-h?rq=1). Note that the answer *doesn't* explicitly state that there's a limit.

Comment: @Glorfindel actually it does "it's only a matter of a few days normally until **a question is no longer eligible to go back to either queue**"

Comment: That's a temporal limit ... but that might be good enough.

Comment: This system seems dysfunctional to me. Suppose I do triage review and pick "needs improvement" because the OP didn't include essential details only known to the OP. The question then ends up in the H&I queue where to only options are to edit (impossible) or flag as VLQ. It then goes back to Triage, even though the question isn't answerable. The system is designed to endlessly shovel dung around between different queues. I stopped doing any of these reviews.

Comment: @Lundin there's a queue that doesn't shovel dung around, but buries it, it has 7.3k items right now ;)

Comment: @Braiam And yet that particularly queue is one of the few that works somewhat ok. I'd be more worried about the 324 H&I and 122 Triage.

Comment: @Lundin: That's exactly what Needs Improvement/Requires Editing is *not* for. That's exactly the case you should use Unsalvageable for. See e.g. [the faq about Triage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674), which specifically and strongly recommends against using RE for cases where the question needs *author* editing specifically. Following this rule will prevent endless shuffling.

Comment: @Lundin: It's been well known for years that [the Triage UI is misleading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321895) and (among other issues) leads to well-meaning triagers filling the Help and Improvement queue with unsalvageable questions. The FAQ linked by Nathan does a pretty good job of explaining how Triage should *really* be done, but since most triagers never read it (or even know that it exists), it doesn't help much. The devs apparently don't care, as long as the system still *kind of* works. Personally, I long ago decided to follow their example and stop caring about review on SO too.

Comment: I have a question regarding that flow. There are two arrows coming out of  "*Help and improvement queue / ...*", but that's not a decision box. What really happens when a question is marked as "*Requires editing*"? (not "*Should be improved*"; I guess the flow is outdated there)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Well, they did recently make Triage link to that selfsame FAQ in the top review instruction box, so things are not perhaps quite as hopeless as one might think.

Comment: @giusti: The chart is a bit confusing, but in practice H&I actually *is* a decision point, as a small right-side link can be used to kick the post out by flagging VLQ, which, in general, has the result of pushing it back into Triage.

Comment: So marking as VLQ always send it back to Triage, even after it someone said it required editing and someone else responded with VLQ? But... the VLQ UI says "*This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing*", and then it goes to a queue where two of the three options are "*Looks OK*" and "**Requires Editing**"??? SO, you're drunk. Go home.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom as per the diagram Triage decision box goes to `Dispute flags raised in triage` box if someone takes `should be improved` (aka `requires editing`) decision. I wonder what does this `flags raised` mean here? While reviewing the posts in triage queue,  reviewers don't have any action like upvote, downvote, flag, edit etc  visible then how can someone flag a post during triaging and still mark it as `requires editing`?

Comment: @RBT If the _overall outcome_ of triage is Requires Editing, then flags raised (by other users who chose Unsalvageable) will be disputed.  The Unsalvageable button actually brings up the flag dialog, so that's how flags (or close votes, if the triager has the privilege) are cast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Let's say it first comes for Triage. Then somebody marks it as "Requires Editing". So it goes to Help and Improvement queue. When that post reaches "Help and Improvement" queue then someone marks it as "question is very low quality" so it will go to "Low Quality Posts" queue.

No, it will go back to triage, and continue that loop until the post becomes not eligible to enter either queue, at this point the loops break off. Low quality review queue doesn't accept questions, only answers, while triage and H&I queues only accept questions. There's no cross over between both groups.

> Also when I mark a post as "Unsalvageable" in Triage queue, will it go to "Low Quality Posts" queue?

No, it will go to the close queue.

> How does a post reach to Triage review queue? Is it due to some action taken by an SO user, e.g. flagging?

When the system (quality filters, AFAIK) has no confidence that the question is "ok", but can't reject it either, it gets send to triage. Also, user flagging a question as VLQ also sends these to triage.

References:

- [Where do the Posts in Triage Section of the Reviews come from?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298843/792066)
- [HIQ "very low quality" link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288385/792066)
- [Is there a limit to how many times a question can get sent back to Triage from H&I?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289749/792066)

Comment: I'm just describing how the system works, not that I agree with it nor that it can be improved.

Comment: Keep in mind that in some circumstances flagging a post in the H&I as VLQ will push it into a moderator queue.

Comment: @TinyGiant only when it is no longer elegible for the triage queue (has an upvote, 7 days on the site, etc.)

Comment: How can a user mark an answer as low-quality? While flagging an answer I see only these 4 options - `spam`, `rude or abusive` , `not an answer`,  `in need of moderator intervention`. Which flag out of these 4 is termed as `low-quality` flag?

Comment: @RBT low quality flag option is only available if the answer is score<=0 or less than ~7 days old

Comment: Super! I've full clarity now. Actually the most important learning for me was that `Low Quality Posts` contain ONLY answer posts. I failed to observe that pattern during my review activity. That distinction removed lot of doubts. Actually description of the `Low Quality Posts` also says `Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts` where `posts` can mean both question or answer. I believe description should be made more clear like `Identify, then improve or delete low-quality answers` instead. Description of `Triage` and `H&I` review queue is crystal clear in that sense.