# Change the description of Low Quality Posts review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

It had been mind baffling experience understanding the whole work flow of how review queue works. I also posted a question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341149/how-does-a-post-reach-the-help-and-improvement-queue) to understand it fully. One of the most important finding which was the root cause of some of my confusion was the type of posts which get injected into "Low Quality Posts" review queue.

I feel that the current description of "Low Quality Posts" review queue is confusing. Here is what it currently stands at:

> Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts

Now have a look at the description of other two queues:

1. Help and Improvement queue: "Help improve questions by editing"
2. Triage queue: "Help identify the quality of questions"

Description of both the above queues have the term "questions" in them which is clearly evident of the fact that I should expect question posts in these two review queues.

While the description of the "Low Quality Posts" queue doesn't use the term "answers". It simply uses the terms "posts". "posts" word is used synonymous for both question as well as answer post on Stack Overflow.

I think this is a very small verbiage change but I strongly feel that this requires a change. The description of "Low Quality Posts" queue should be changed to:

> Identify, then improve or delete low-quality answers

The sole reason behind suggesting this change is the fact that this review queue *always* contains low quality answers. It *never* contains low quality questions.

Comment: It's only on Stack Overflow that LQ review is restricted to answers. On other sites (which don't have Triage or Help&Improvement) it contains questions, too. This is not to say the language shouldn't be adjusted on Stack Overflow... just for context.

Comment: Yeah, having a separate string for Stack Overflow just to change "posts" to "answers" is probably not gonna happen. Note that your description change would also warrant changing the *title* of the queue. Doesn't make sense to call the queue Low Quality *Posts* and then only say *answers* in the description.

Comment: @animuson would it make more sense dropping "posts" and leaving it as "Low quality review queue"?

Comment: Do note that questions are still served up as audits in the LQPQ

Comment: I agree with @braiam. If we look at both `Triage` queue and `H&I` queue, their names don't use the word `post`, `question` or `answer` in their name. Contents of the queue are clarified by their description. Same should apply for LQP review queue and it can be named as `Low Quality Review Queue` and then in the description we can describe appropriately that it contains only answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver are you sure? U mean literally question posts are also served up in LQPQ or you mean those new answer posts in which new users many a times end up asking new questions mistakenly?

Comment: @RBT Questions used to be in the LQPQ.  When they stopped serving up questions they never stopped the question audits.  So now you will be going along and every once and a while you will get an actual question.  You know when that happens that you are looking at an audit.

Comment: The "low quality review queue", where we do low-quality reviews? No, that won't work. You would have to omit the word "review".

Comment: Yeah. Makes sense. It should be `Low Quality Queue` rather.

Comment: I vote for "the dung pile".

Comment: @NathanOliver that's an artifact/bug, since the LQRQ still shows questions elsewhere.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm doing low quality post review daily and consuming my daily quota of 20 reviews. In fact, I had been doing it for long now but it is just that now I'm more cautiously observing the audits also whenever I came across one. It had been several days now and whenever I encountered an audit post it turned out to be an answer. I have serious doubts that they still serve questions posts as audit in LQP review queue in stackoverflow.

Comment: @rbt see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289627/why-does-lqp-still-have-question-audits

Comment: @NathanOliver finaly I witnessesed an audit *question* post in the LQP queue myself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14990092). I passed the audit :).