# Why is 'question is very low quality' button on the right bottom in Help and Improvement review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, hyperlinks, help-improvement

I recently discovered that there is a 'question is very low quality' hyperlink in the Help and Improvement queue which I had never noticed before. Is this a Work In Progress feature? I could not understand why this hyperlink would be available at this corner where it can be easily missed by people in the beginning when they start this review queue. What makes it different from the buttons at the top that ask for 'Edit' or 'Skip'? I can also see that 'link' also seems redundant as clicking on the question anyways takes the reviewer to the original content and most people would open it in a new tab if they want to stay in the queue, but if need be it can stay here since this is not an action.
[image]

Comment: I believe it's because questions are put in the H&I queue if requires editing is pressed in another queue. The button is then for you to disagree and say it is very low quality, but as other's have already reviewed it, it is believed not to be very low quality, hence the button is not obvious. Maybe?

Comment: VLQ questions that are marked "need editing" in the triage queue when they should be deleted are sent over to the H&I review queue. This looks like a measure against robo-reviewing.

Comment: [see the workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjvml.png)

Comment: @gnat, I could see a never ending loop there: Triage -> H&I -> Triage. Is there a method to prevent such?

Comment: On a side note, There are many questions for which I use that link. Questions that just dump an error message with no code, or questions that give a vague description of a problem/requirements without any background on the needs for a solution or without any code. When I encounter a few of these VLQ's in a row I occasionally have to click the link twice, as no action happens when I click the confirmation button from the pop-up warning.

Comment: @Luuklag yeah there is a loop, see [Is there a limit to how many times a question can get sent back to Triage from H&I?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289749/839601)

Comment: @gnat good to know. I wonder if there are any statistics on how many times a question has been send round in circles