# Why is this question not ok?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, triage, spam

[I failed this audit in triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8936249) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKHWJ.png)).
The description of why it wasn't "ok" was that it was spam or complete nonsense.
I don't think the question was spam *or* complete nonsense, so does someone here have a better explanation for why I failed this review?

On a side note, I was suspended from reviewing as a result of this failure.

Comment: The question contains a (deleted) *answer* which was spam, could it be that it was that what was being reviewed?

Comment: @Pekka I don't believe so.  This link I posted is what I saw when I clicked "Looks OK"

Comment: Are you literate in Wordpress?  If not, maybe you should have skipped it?  I would probably have skipped it being illiterate in Wordpress (is that a new way of spelling WordStar?) — or I might have been caught like you.  I mostly gave up on review because I got fed up with failing audits.  I can be more useful editing instead.

Comment: @Jonathan - it was clearly off-topic and needed to be nuked, although it was not spam.

Comment: @Pekka웃: to me, it was not clearly off-topic.  Neither was it clearly on-topic.  Hence I would have ducked, probably by filtering to areas of semi-competence.  You may have a better understanding; that won't be hard.  But the quoted content is not clearly anything except 'out of scope' for me.

Comment: Don't feel too bad.  I've failed the audit questions before in cases where I completely disagree with the reasons given.  Most times they're spot on, but on a couple occasions I've been left wondering what they were smoking to come up with the conclusions that they did.  Part of being a community, we're not all going to see everything in exactly the same light.  As explicit as the rules are, there's *still* subjectivity to them!  :-)

Comment: What is ok about this question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, the question is:

> #### How can I batch update featured images to posts on Wordpress?
>
> I want to set the same features image for each post in a category. The image is not used in the post itself, but it is in the image gallery. I can take care of the future, but I need some way to go back and update the 500 previous posts in 3-4 categories to the new images.
>
> How might I go about that?
>
> [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress)

It was voted on exactly once, a downvote, deleted a handful of days after posting, and the poster is deleted.
There's a long spam-answer (poster different and also deleted, posted ~1h before it was handled, a minute before the question was deleted by community) and a short link-only answer.

As you can see, while it *might* be somewhat low quality, it certainly doesn't *look* spammy (though *it seems* it was deleted as such).

Now, we can speculate how it came to that:

- Post got a SPAM-flag (and thus the downvote), and user deleted account leading to auto-deletion and validation of SPAM-flag.
  This is unlikely, because the question and answer were deleted just a minute apart.
- Post got a SPAM-flag, and mod deleted account as part of a SPAM-ring (maybe the two deleted accounts are both socks of the same spammer).
  That's my best reconstruction.

---

Someone knowing slightly more about wordpress (I know next to nothing) clarified that the question is actually unclear without an MCVE, which might explain the link-only answer it got. So, classifying it as "Looks Ok" seems to be wrong despite it not looking spammy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  It's just a shame, because I failed 3 audits in a week a little while back, and so I had to wait for 2 days.  I honestly did my best to understand why all of my reviews were bad, tried to improve my awareness, and become a better community member.  This is now a few days after I could start answering again, and to my knowledge this is the first failed audit (after several good ones).  My account is now suspended from reviewing again, but this time for a week.

Comment: Even if all that is true, there is *no way* the reviewer could have know that, is there? Isn't Triage supposed to be based on the question, not on the answers (spam or otherwise) it attracts? Now, I agree with [durron597](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300246/1426065) that there are issues with the question that could warrant a close vote, but IMO it's *borderline* OK.

Comment: @MattDMo _there is no way the reviewer could have know that, is there?_ - The reviewer could have known that the question is unclear without an MCVE if they were familiar enough with Wordpress, or the reviewer could have skipped if they weren't familiar enough with Wordpress to tell whether this is answerable as is or needs more info.

Answer (score 58):

I can provide a little context on this question. The reason why this appeared as an audit is because it was flagged as spam and deleted. That validated the spam flag and caused it to be used as an audit case.

Why that question was flagged as spam had to do with one of the answers. For a couple of months now, a clever spam ring has been posting spam for "Easy Data Feed" and other related products. They do this by first seeding well-written but completely off topic questions in a series of tags (usually [e-commerce], [scrape], and [web-scraping]), then answering them with their spam. The question will be posted on a different account than the spam answer, with the answer sometimes coming days later.

At the request of myself and other moderators, folks in the Tavern have been watching for this and flagging spam seed questions and their answers as they come in. Usually, they use spam flags only on the obvious spam answers and "other" flags on the questions, but occasionally they use spam flags on both. We're usually in a hurry to delete the whole thing, and we appreciate the help, so maybe we're not always as discriminating as to whether the question would appear to be wrong to someone not aware of this and don't dispute spam flags on them.

Also, sometimes we'll use a hard moderator spam flag on the question itself (immediately destroying the post), because that can trigger the anti-spam system to immediately stop any new posts from a location for a short duration. I think that might have been used here.

This is probably the most borderline of the ones I've seen, so I've cleared the spam flag on this (stopping it from being used as an audit). I've also lifted your review ban, since you couldn't have known all this.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, and for the consideration in lifting my ban. I'll do my best to be more careful in the future, too.

Comment: I missed that we need to flag spam seeds as other. I left a link to this post in the Tavern on the Meta. I might have been one of the spam flaggers.

Answer (score 17):

So apparently I am the [only person](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24682077#24682077) to have [passed this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8848809). A few thoughts about it:

I thought this question could be validly closed in no less than three close reasons:

1. **unclear what you're asking**

- There is very little information about how his wordpress system is set up. I want more details to understand what is going on, to be able to help him change his pictures as he needs.

2. **too broad**

- This is the default close reason that I use for question that seems to show almost no effort; one that completely fails the "what have you tried" test. I know it's not homework, but [this is the post that made me start using this close reason in this situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216577/200235)

3. **questions seeking debugging help should provide a clear problem statement and an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

- This is related to #1. Again, there's just not enough information here to productively help this person.

I have [long argued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293463/1768232) for the Triage language to be changed (and I'm [not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288779/1768232) and [neither is he](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289738/1768232)), but until the Triage language gives me an interface to vote to close a question without clicking Unsalvageable, I'm going to keep clicking it.

Comment: Are you knowledgeable in WordPress? If so, do you think that helped you in making your decision? As someone who does not have knowledge of WordPress (I've *never* used it.), I can't really say much at all about whether there's enough info in the question for someone who is. I would have just pressed Skip. So I'm interested to know whether your reasoning might be based on knowledge I don't have.

Comment: @jpmc26 I haven't, but I've reviewed quite a few Wordpress questions and it seemed pretty clear to me.

Comment: Agree with #2 for not doing his homework. Disagree on #1 and #3... not quite sure what type of mcve you would be expecting, the question looks quite clear to me and a 5 seconds Google search for "batch changing featured image wordpress" gives the answer...