# How to deal with potential spam seeds?

Tags: support, questions, spam, spam-seeds

I stumbled upon this **awful** question:

[How to use upload image in c sharp with wcf service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760003)

[image: possible spam seed?]

The question was utterly rubbish. Made no sense whatsoever. So I did my duty: down-voted and voted to close as *"unclear what you're asking":

I must admit I wasn't 100% sure it was a [spam seed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256709), so I left a comment for the community:

> *"Is this a bad spam seed? :p"*

Then I saw the question was removed *"for reasons of moderation"* so I started to wonder if I did the correct action.

So, in addition to down-vote and vote to close, what should I do if I suspect a question is a spam seed? Flag as spam or flag for moderator intervention?

Comment: Do you not consider "removed for reasons of moderation" as the appropriate action taken then? Should the message be different?

Comment: @Jongware Sure, but if we assume that a moderator didn't see the question then someone must have done something to make a moderator aware of the question right?

Comment: Most of the spam-seeds I see are rather clever and easy missed as they are seen as legit questions. Once they get an answer they reveal their real identity. The example you found doesn't look like a spam seed, rather an attempt (from possible a spammer) to figure out how markdown works. Notice that the post isn't marked as spam, not even by the mod who deleted it.

Comment: @rene: ah, so there is a dedicated "this be Spam" delete reason? (I do agree with your Probing Theory.)

Comment: As a side note: The [SO Close Vote Reviewers Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) gets reports for known SPAM. You could leave a message there if you find a post that needs flags...

Comment: @rene So the correct action would be to use the custom moderator flag then? Thanks for the screenshot btw.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå No, I don't think a mod flag is needed. That post needs LQ flags, downvotes, close votes but I'm not sure about a spam flag. We don't need a mod to get that question of the site but it might need quick attention from more users, hence my suggestion to run to a chatroom for help

Comment: @Jongware I don't know if there is a delete-as-spam option but I do know that mods have options to mark either the account or the post as spam, and I believe that is separate from spam flags raised by us mortals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, that **wasn't** a spam seed. Spam seeds are rather cleverly disguised, so much that they even trick [reviewers if used in an audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300234/why-is-this-question-not-ok).

Once they get an answer they reveal their true identity. The example seems an attempt (from possibly a spammer) to figure out how markdown works. Notice that the post isn't marked as spam, not even by [Flexo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) who deleted it.

I don't think a mod flag is needed. That post needs LQ flags, down votes, close votes but not a spam flag. We don't need a mod to get that question off the site, but it might need quick attention from more users. Hence my suggestion to run to a chatroom for help, for example, the [SO Close Vote Reviewers room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

If you do see a spam seed question (and once more, that isn't easy) I'll copy the relevant content from the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300294/578411) from [Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) (who seems to be head chief spam handler):

> At the request of myself and other moderators, folks in the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) have been watching for this and flagging spam seed questions and their answers as they come in. Usually, they use spam flags only on the obvious spam answers and "other" flags on the questions, but occasionally they use spam flags on both

So the preferred action for spam seed questions is to flag as other but clearly state that it is a spam seed (because it attracted a spam answer, because it is used across the network, because Brad told you to, etc.) otherwise moderators might decline your flag. Down votes and close votes help to get the question off the main page while your flag is handled.

Spam answers can be flagged as spam.

Comment: I apologize if this is obvious, but: what is a spam seed?

Comment: A spam seed is a question that only exist for the purpose to have another spam account provide an answer, promoting the product. So the question states, simply put, *How do I lose weight* and the answer promotes and links to the website to get those fabulous *diet pills that let you lose all that fat without doing any exercise or eat less* @Jashaszun