# Questions flagged as duplicate being disputed

Tags: support

Lately I've seen a couple of my duplicate flags being disputed. Although I do understand what disputed means, I'm a bit confused as to how this is possible?

When I did some research, I've came across these meta posts about the disputed flag:

[What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) Where the highly upvoted and accepted answer says:

> Currently, the following scenarios may result in a flag being
>   disputed:
>
> - A spam or offensive flag which is cleared (but not declined) by a    moderator. These flags are unique in that they can impose lasting
>     penalties on both the post and author, so a special mechanism is
>     provided for them to be cleared without penalizing either the author
>     or the flagger.
> - A Not An Answer flag or Very Low Quality flag is reviewed in the Low Quality review queue, and the result of the review is "Looks OK".
> - A Recommend Close flag is active on a post reviewed in the Triage review queue when the result of the review is "Looks OK".
> - A Spam, Offensive, or Very Low Quality flag is active on a post reviewed in the Triage review queue when the result of the review is
>     "Should be Improved".

Which doesn't include the Marked as Duplicate flag.

Looking just a little further, there's also this question:

[What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags) Where the accepted answer says:

> Disputed flag: When you flag an answer as NAA or VLQ and the post
>   doesn't result in deletion but someone recommended deletion, the flag
>   is disputed. Spam and offensive flags on post that are rolled back are
>   also disputed.

Which also doesn't explain that a Duplicate flag can be disputed. So are these meta posts outdated or do I miss something somewhere?

Edit: As requested, an example:

[image: Duplicate question disputed]

Now the most odd thing about this example, is that minutes later, someone else still just marked it as a duplicate:

[PHP Rename Access denied code 5. After working it suddenly shows this message [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089786/php-rename-access-denied-code-5-after-working-it-suddenly-shows-this-message)

Comment: Do you have an example of a question where your dupe flag got disputed?

Comment: @rene Of course I do. I've edited my question with the latest example.

Comment: A duplicate flag is a recommend close flag. Blame triage.

Comment: @TZHX Ah, I didn't know a duplicate flag is the same as a close flag. So basicly someone in Triage thought the question was fine and that resulted in my flag being disputed despite I was right. Luckily someone with high enough rating to directly flag the question as a duplicate corrected that mistake. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Here is the [triage review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12275627) that disputed your flag which can be found from the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37089786/timeline)

Comment: Thanks @rene I'll keep an eye on the timeline next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37089786/timeline) of that question you'll see that the question made it, probably due to your flag, into the tiage queue.

When users in the Triage queue were presented with that [task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12275627) they all choose *Looks OK*. I'm not a PHP dev so I can't judge if the reviewers did The Right Thing™.

However, their Looks OK disputes your flag. Luckily an PHP gold badge holder notices the question and decide the question is an duplicate and uses his unilateral vote to close the question.

There are plenty of post on MSO that ask for better guidance for Triage reviewers, like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288779/rephrase-triage-help-text-for-should-be-improved-and-unsalvageable) but I'm not sure if better wording would have helped in this case. The question isn't as low quality as often found in the queue and finding/recognizing duplicates is not something most reviewers take the time for, unfortunately.

Do know that disputed flags doesn't harm in anyway your ability to flag in the future. So it is good to keep an eye on them but don't be too concerned when you pick up an disputed flag now and then.